# REST Complex Resource Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api

So I have been coming across stuff over the last few weeks which is making me improve my understanding of REST.

At work we are having issues with some rest api resource access which has some pretty complex access, so I was wondering if someone could help me understand if/what we are doing wrong and what is the right way go about it.

So the issue we're having is that we have an endpoint for getting all orders. e.g. /orders this endpoint has pagination and filters etc, this endpoint will get a list of orders.

We have two main types of users (admin and account).

If you are an admin, you are able to see all the orders, if you are an account user, it gets a bit more tricky because account users can see orders based on a set of permissions.

So by default, an account user can see all orders that they have placed. They will also be able to see any orders that they have for them. (so this distinction here is that orders are placed by a user, but can be for another. e.g. I might order something for another user).

Due to the way the application is designed, users are able to see orders for other branches as well, one example would be a branch reporter that deals with the orders from all branches and collates reports etc.

So an example for all of this would be:
if you are an administrator, you see all orders by default, if you are an account user, and have permissions for branch x and y, you will see all orders for x & y as well as any orders placed by yourself.

Is the domain design faulty here, is that what's stopping me from seeing a feasible solution?

I have been looking about user contexts a bit so that might be a way to split some of the issues a bit. So an example is different users see different resources in different ways. So to not make a one size fits all solution (which this definitely is) you should build 3 apis. If I did that I could definitely separate admin from account. But I dont know what to do with the complexity of accounts.

[image]

I have a suspicion that the key to this relates to removing these permissions checked out of the database and move them into permission, but I am not sure how one would handle dynamic permissions.

I am sorry if a lot of this is rant or is this doesn't make sense. Any help would be appreciated even if it's only to put me on the right path.
Like I said, I have been trying to understand how to configure REST while trying to forget about the underlying database, but a problem as bonkers as this stumps me.

Comment: Have you been drinking?  :-)
Maybe you could try do sketch this problem into a diagram, that may clear things up.

Comment: I wish :P yer I will add a diagram

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing 2 important aspects, the first is the style you want your API to follow, the second is the authorisation logic you want to apply.

**REST**

If you want to build a consistent, clear, and maintainable rest API first you need to understand your domain.

So what is an Order for you, who is going to consume your API, is your code base unique and so has it to be, or can be split reducing complexity, coupling and increasing the isolation?

If you have a single understanding of Order, just leave it as it is.

**Authorisation**

The authorisation rules are just another example of business logic, and this are often subject to change as the business evolves.
I suggest you to treat the authorisation as you treat any other logic, like when you calculate an order total.
So if you have a service layer, create an Authorisation service where you check what a user is allowed to see.
You can also do it in a filter, so that before returning the list of orders, you apply the security rules and you remove all orders that the user is not supposed to view.
You don't like this approach? Then you need to move the "authorisation filters" down the stack so that the query itself takes it into account.
Based on what you said there are various aspects which you need to account when performing a GetOrderByUserID(x), if you use EF, you can generate the authorisation filters as lambda expression and you can add it to your where clause, making sure you and the necessary joins so that you can take the branch, accounts and so on.

**Conclusion**
It is down to you how you want your system to implement the security, but unless you recognise the existence of multiple domain objects Order, BranchOrder, DelegatedOrder, AccountOrder and so on, in the request there should be no evidence of the security that will be applied afterwards, the only thing is that the authorisation of the REST request has to carry enough details, likely in the headers, to identify who is requesting the resources.
Also note that even if you break down your domain object (Order) into more specific types of order, you will still need to apply security, and therefore you will still need to create and maintain the security rules.

Your question is a bit broad and with just enough information to give you hints, if you want a more specific answer, you need to update your question to be more specific as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have code level access at "orders" end. Then you can design in this way.

1. Make the user's id as a mandatory input at the "Orders" end. So whenever any user calls the API, he should make the request with parameters of User ID.
2. Once you get the user ID at "orders" end, check the authorization of user such as whether user is admin or not and user has access to which branch.
3. Now, Limit the data in response accordingly.

You should make the changes at "Orders" end to authorize, filter the data and sending the response accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, but the issue is not the transportation of the user id, it is instead the complex authorization check.
The user id of the requested will be gotten by the claim in their security token.
But once the service has that (no matter if it is from the claim (which it should be) or a request parameter) there is complex permission checking on all the orders.
If they are an account user, then each order will need to be checked to see if the order is for the user, or was ordered by the user or is for a branch the user has access to